# Getting negative/wrong values although using identifier "long"

Tags: java, numbers, long-integer

I am trying to calculate the sum of the first, even four million Fibonacci-numbers. However, after a while, only the Y-values are being printed out as the values get larger, even though I'm using the identifier long.

These are the start values:

```
long amount = 4000000;
long x = 1;
long y = 2;
long sum = 2;
```

Here is a for-loop that sums up and prints out the numbers as the program runs.

```
for (int i = 0; i < amount - 1; i++) {
    if (x > y) {
        y = x + y;
        if (y % 2 == 0) {
            sum += y;
        }           
        System.out.println("X: " + x);
    } else {
        x = x + y;
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            sum += x;
        }   
        System.out.println("Y: " + y);
    }
}
System.out.println("Summa: " + sum);
```

First Fibonacci numbers output correctly:

```
Y: 2
X: 3
Y: 5
X: 8
Y: 13
X: 21
Y: 34
X: 55
Y: 89
X: 144
Y: 233
X: 377
```

Output after a while:

```
X: 8838822096666553613
Y: 9212367363430683303
Y: 9212367363430683303
Y: 9212367363430683303
Y: 9212367363430683303
Y: 9212367363430683303
Y: 9212367363430683303
Y: 9212367363430683303
Y: 9212367363430683303
Y: 9212367363430683303
Y: 9212367363430683303
Y: 9212367363430683303
```

Why is only `Y` getting calculated after a while? Is my code wrong?

Comment: `X` overflows and becomes negative, so `(x > y)` is always false

Comment: What identifier should I use then?

Comment: long max value is 2^63 so you're at the limit. Use BigInteger

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it!

Comment: @Toumash to be accurate the long max value is 2^63-1

Comment: @Mourad Kourie you dont need to try it. I took 3 secounds to calculate the first 10000 with your algorithem, so you wont be able to calculate the first four million with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number you're calculating is quite big... too big for a Long. Since you're doing integer calculations, replace the `long` for a `BigInteger`. Since `BigInteger` is an object, you won't be able to use the + or % operators, and you'll need to use the method calls `add()` and `mod()`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum value a `long` can take is `9223372036854775807` (`Long.MAX_VALUE`). If the result of an addition exceeds that, it will overflow and return a negative value :

```
long x = 8838822096666553613L;
long y = 9212367363430683303L;
y = x + y;
```

will result in a `y` value of `-395554613612314700`. Therefore this comparison will fail :

```
if (x > y) {
```

and this is why you only see `Y` values getting printed